# Remove object in List based on content

Tags: java, list

I am currently learning Java and I have a tricky question that I couldn't answer...
So I started developping a Shopping cart with the possibility to add and remove items, but then came to my mind what if intead of removing the item itself I ask to remove the item created the same way? Explaination :

```
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
Item.item = new Item("corn flakes", 500);
cart.addItem(item);
cart.removeItem(new Item("corn flakes", 500));
System.out.println(cart.itemCount()); // Supposed to display 0
```

Well here if I execute the code, it will display "1" instead of "0".

The question is how do I get this to work?

Here's the code of ShoppingCart

`
public class ShoppingCart {
    List items;

```
public ShoppingCart() {
    this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}

public void addItem(Item item) {
    this.items.add(item);
}

public void removeItem(Item item) {
    this.items.remove(item);
}


public int itemCount() {
    return this.items.size();
}

public int totalPrice() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(Item item : items)
        sum += item.getPrice();
    return sum;
}
```

}
`

Thanks :)

Comment: what is the code for `removeItem`?

Comment: Can you share `ShoppingCart`'s code? How does it hold `Item`s?

Comment: `public void removeItem(Item item) {
  this.items.remove(item);
}`

Comment: Have you implemented equals method properly on Item?

Comment: It depends, how you collect items? And how you remove an item? You override equals and hashCode right?

Comment: Actually no, I just use the add method in a List of object

Comment: You can implement `equals` method in your class `Item`. And in `removeItem` method, search for existing items and remove accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your underlying implementation of ShoppingCart it is hard to answer you. But I would guess that you are storing it in an ArrayList, and if so you will need to override equals() on Item and then call remove on the ArrayList. At the moment your code is only comparing the references to the Item's in your list, so creating a new Item and trying to delete it will always fail.

You need to do something like this

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if(that == null || !(that instanceof Item))
        return false;
    return this.name.equals(that.name) && this.quantity == that.quantity;
}
```

Comment: should use this.name.equals(that.name)

Comment: So I added the equals method but then how would I use it in the ShoppingCart?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you're backing your `ShoppingCart` with a `List` of some sort, the docs for the `List` interface appears to hold the answer to your question:

```
...removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists).
```

([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29))

If you're using the `remove(Object o)` method of a `List,` it uses the `equals()` method internally to look for the object to remove. However, the default `equals()' method for an`Object` is this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

In other words, it tests for reference equality -- whether two references point to exactly the same object. If you did not override `equals()` in your `Item` class, this is the `equals()` method that your backing `List` uses to look for the element to remove. The problem is that when you create a new `Item` to remove, its reference is *not* pointing at the same variable as the original `Item` you put in; thus, the `remove()` method does not find an object that is "equal" to the original object you put in, and so removes nothing.

Long story short, for this to work correctly, you'll need to override `equals()` to compare the contents of the object, rather than the references to the objects.